# Long article problem in bootstrap responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

While i was coding simple a website,a problem appeared
problem is that i want to write a long article without space by using bootstrap(responsive) but i guess bootstrap has a bug. i divided it into 3 div, 1- left div 2-middle div 3 - right div.When i write a long article in middle div, it overflow to right div.However,if i write with space i don't have a problem. How can i solve this problem?

You can see photos
Div part:

[image]

code part:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<body>

    <header>
    <!-- Ust Kısım -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <img class="img-fluid" width="125" height="50" src="logo2.png"/>
                </div>
                <div id="arama_cubugu" class="col-4">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">                        
                            <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="arama_buton" class="col-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Hemen Ara</button>
                </div>
                <div id="sag_ust_giris" class="col-4">
                    Giriş Yap
                </div>
            </div>
                <hr/>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- İçerik kısmı -->
        <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="row">
                    <!-- SOL KISIM -->
                    <div id="sol" class="col-2">
                    Sol deneme
                    </div>  
                    <!-- ORTA KISIM -->
                    <div id="orta" class="col-6">
                        <div class="container">
                            <!-- Orta kısım üst alanı -->
                            <div class="row">                               
                                <div class="col-4">
                                BEĞEN / BEĞENME
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                Paylaşan KROOXXPİİSWWQ_R
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Web Adı -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-8">
                                www.gogle.com
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Web Description -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                Deneme Deneme Deneme DenemeDeneme DenemeDeneme DenemeDeneme DenemeDeneme DenemeDeneme Deneme Deneme Deneme

                                </div>      
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- YORUM DİVİ -->
                    <div id="yorum"  class="col-4">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- Kullanıcı_adı -->
                                <div class="col-4">
                                Hakan
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- Yorum -->
                                <div class="col-12">
                                çok iyi çok güzel çookçok iyi çok güzel çookçok iyi çok güzel çookçok iyi çok güzel çookçok iyi çok güzel çookçok iyi çok güzel çook
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2">
                                </div>
                                <!-- Yorum etiket -->
                                <div class="col-10">
                                #matematik #problemler
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  


            </div>


</body>
```

Comment: please add your code as text to the question

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp Try using CSS word-break: break-all or break-word on the text

Comment: share your code code please